# Unit-root test in Minitab

Tags: unit-root, minitab

I've read that Minitab does not perform the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test; I can't find it myself. Is there an alternative function in the package that will run a unit-root test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Minitab but this Excel add-in will perform an ADF test: http://www.web-reg.de/adf_addin.html